# Mysql run where clause if value = 'x'?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I would like to do is to run a where clause only if a certain value (that will be loaded dynamically) = a certain value. For example

`IF ('<=' == '$dynamic_value') THEN WHERE...`

Is this possible? (the $dynamic value will either be <=, or >=)

In other words, I would like to use the where clause only when certain value happens or invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE 
    CASE '$dynamic_value' 
        WHEN '>=' THEN column_a >= column_b AND other_conditions
        WHEN '<=' THEN column_a <= column_b AND other_conditions
        ELSE 1
    END
```

If `$dynamic_value` does not equal to either `>=` or `<=`, the `ELSE 1` will be used by the `WHERE` clause instead - which is basically like having no `WHERE` clause at all (and return all records).

Since it seems like you're using PHP and the value of `$dynamic_value` can only be `>=` or `<=`, you can just insert the parameter directly like:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE column_a $dynamic_value column_b";
```

Of course if coming from user-input, then be sure you're checking whether `$dynamic_value` is either `>=` or `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an `IF` condition, this is typically handled with boolean logic in the `WHERE`. Match your dynamic value with and `AND` it together with its corresponding condition.

```
WHERE
  ('$dynamic_value' = '<=' AND othercolumn = othercondition)
  OR ('$dynamic_value' = '>=' AND othercolumn = someothercondition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar *effect* with something like:

```
WHERE $dynamic_value <> '<=' OR <your-other-clause>
```

That way, the `<your-other-clause>` bit will have no effect unless the `$dynamic_value` is set to `'<='`.